# Python Youtube Web Scraper not working properly

Tags: python, web-scraping, youtube

So i built this small script that would give back a URL of any searched video on youtube. But after opening it up again turns out that the web scraping with youtube is not working out properly. As when printing `soup` it returns something completely different than from what can be seen with inspect element on Youtube. Can someone help me solve this...
Heres My Code:

```
import requests
from lxml import html
import webbrowser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import tkinter
from pytube import YouTube

headers= {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.162 Safari/537.36"}

def video_finder():
    word = input("Enter video title: ")
    if ' ' in word:
        new = word.replace(' ', '+')
        print(new)
    else:
        pass

    vid = requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query={}'.format(new))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(vid.text, features='lxml')
    all_vids = soup.find_all('div', id_='contents')
    print(all_vids)
    video1st = all_vids[0]
    a_Tag = video1st.find('a', class_="yt-uix-tile-link yt-ui-ellipsis yt-ui-ellipsis-2 yt-uix-sessionlink spf-link", href=True)
    Video_name = a_Tag.text
    Video_id = a_Tag['href']
    video_link = 'https://www.youtube.com' + Video_id
    print(Video_name)
    print(video_link)
```

Its not the best but ye... thank you

Comment: https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl is the best tool around.

You're importing "pytube", but you aren't really using it - you should check their manual.

Comment: @avloss, yes because its in the latter part of the code and I only put up the part I was having trouble with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get correct result from Youtube page, set `User-Agent` HTTP header to Googlebot, and use  `html.parser` in BeautifulSoup.

For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers= {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"}
def video_finder():
    word = input("Enter video title: ")

    params = {
        'search_query': word
    }

    vid = requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/results', params=params, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(vid.content, features='html.parser')
    a_Tag = soup.find('a', class_="yt-uix-tile-link yt-ui-ellipsis yt-ui-ellipsis-2 yt-uix-sessionlink spf-link", href=lambda h: h.startswith('/watch?'))
    Video_name = a_Tag.text
    Video_id = a_Tag['href']
    video_link = 'https://www.youtube.com' + Video_id
    print(Video_name)
    print(video_link)

video_finder()
```

Prints:

```
Enter video title: sailor moon
Sailor Moon Opening (English) *HD*
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5txHGxJRwtQ
```

Comment: thanks a lot man, the solution works perfectly. So I modified my own code and all I needed to change was the headers. Can you maybe explain why that is?

Comment: @RutvikKarupothula Some servers return different HTML code based on this header - for example they're protecting from bots etc.